# Modified the code for grep function

Tags: r

I have several columns in my dataset which start with Q(m,n,s)_. How can I extract these columns from the data set. I tried to use the below code but it didn't work. I was wondering how I can fix the problem.

```
col <-grep("Q(m,n,s)_",names(Data))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape those parenthesis, parenthesis have special meanings in regex, they are called capture groups, hence to take their literal meaning we have to escape them, It is better to put your names of column while posting so that everything can be verified:

```
grep("Q\\(m,n,s\\)_",names(Data))
```

In case you want a logical return, use `grepl` :

```
grepl("Q\\(m,n,s\\)_",names(Data))
```

**Toy example:**

```
x1 <- c("Q(m,n,s)_","a,b,c")
y1 <- grepl("Q\\(m,n,s\\)_",x1)

> y1
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than wrestling with regex patterns is using the `fixed = TRUE` parameter:

```
col <- grep("Q(m,n,s)_", names(Data), fixed = TRUE)
```

If you want the names, than add the `value = TRUE` parameter:

```
col <- grep("Q(m,n,s)_", names(Data), fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```